# Api state control in redux i.e PENDING, SUCCESS, FAILURE in react-redux jhipster generated code

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jhipster

In the below jhipster generated code, how the pending, success and failure of actions are being triggered? For each action type we use, it is being appended with _PENDING or _SUCCESS or _FAILURE and I'm not able to figure out where and how it happens.
As I see pending, success and failure states are being handled by the reducer I don't understand when and where those actions are being triggered.

For example in the code below, the first action has type ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_MEDICINE_LIST = 'medicine/FETCH_MEDICINE_LIST'.

The actions that actually gets triggered are medicine/FETCH_MEDICINE_LIST_PENDING, medicine/FETCH_MEDICINE_LIST_SUCCESS, medicine/FETCH_MEDICINE_LIST_FAILURE when medicine/FETCH_MEDICINE_LIST action gets trigger. Where and how the Api state actions are being triggered?

```
import { ICrudGetAction, ICrudGetAllAction, ICrudPutAction, ICrudDeleteAction } from 'react-jhipster';

import { cleanEntity } from 'app/shared/util/entity-utils';
import { REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE } from 'app/shared/reducers/action-type.util';

import { IMedicine, defaultValue } from 'app/shared/model/medicine.model';

export const ACTION_TYPES = {
  FETCH_MEDICINE_LIST: 'medicine/FETCH_MEDICINE_LIST',
  FETCH_MEDICINE: 'medicine/FETCH_MEDICINE',
  CREATE_MEDICINE: 'medicine/CREATE_MEDICINE',
  UPDATE_MEDICINE: 'medicine/UPDATE_MEDICINE',
  DELETE_MEDICINE: 'medicine/DELETE_MEDICINE',
  RESET: 'medicine/RESET'
};

const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  errorMessage: null,
  entities: [] as ReadonlyArray<IMedicine>,
  entity: defaultValue,
  updating: false,
  updateSuccess: false
};

export type MedicineState = Readonly<typeof initialState>;

// Reducer

export default (state: MedicineState = initialState, action): MedicineState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST(ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_MEDICINE_LIST):
    case REQUEST(ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_MEDICINE):
      return {
        ...state,
        errorMessage: null,
        updateSuccess: false,
        loading: true
      };
    case REQUEST(ACTION_TYPES.CREATE_MEDICINE):
    case REQUEST(ACTION_TYPES.UPDATE_MEDICINE):
    case REQUEST(ACTION_TYPES.DELETE_MEDICINE):
      return {
        ...state,
        errorMessage: null,
        updateSuccess: false,
        updating: true
      };
    case FAILURE(ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_MEDICINE_LIST):
    case FAILURE(ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_MEDICINE):
    case FAILURE(ACTION_TYPES.CREATE_MEDICINE):
    case FAILURE(ACTION_TYPES.UPDATE_MEDICINE):
    case FAILURE(ACTION_TYPES.DELETE_MEDICINE):
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        updating: false,
        updateSuccess: false,
        errorMessage: action.payload
      };
    case SUCCESS(ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_MEDICINE_LIST):
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        entities: action.payload.data
      };
    case SUCCESS(ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_MEDICINE):
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        entity: action.payload.data
      };
    case SUCCESS(ACTION_TYPES.CREATE_MEDICINE):
    case SUCCESS(ACTION_TYPES.UPDATE_MEDICINE):
      return {
        ...state,
        updating: false,
        updateSuccess: true,
        entity: action.payload.data
      };
    case SUCCESS(ACTION_TYPES.DELETE_MEDICINE):
      return {
        ...state,
        updating: false,
        updateSuccess: true,
        entity: {}
      };
    case ACTION_TYPES.RESET:
      return {
        ...initialState
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const apiUrl = 'api/medicines';

// Actions

export const getEntities: ICrudGetAllAction<IMedicine> = (page, size, sort) => ({
  type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_MEDICINE_LIST,
  payload: axios.get<IMedicine>(`${apiUrl}?cacheBuster=${new Date().getTime()}`)
});

export const getEntity: ICrudGetAction<IMedicine> = id => {
  const requestUrl = `${apiUrl}/${id}`;
  return {
    type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_MEDICINE,
    payload: axios.get<IMedicine>(requestUrl)
  };
};

export const createEntity: ICrudPutAction<IMedicine> = entity => async dispatch => {
  const result = await dispatch({
    type: ACTION_TYPES.CREATE_MEDICINE,
    payload: axios.post(apiUrl, cleanEntity(entity))
  });
  dispatch(getEntities());
  return result;
};

export const updateEntity: ICrudPutAction<IMedicine> = entity => async dispatch => {
  const result = await dispatch({
    type: ACTION_TYPES.UPDATE_MEDICINE,
    payload: axios.put(apiUrl, cleanEntity(entity))
  });
  dispatch(getEntities());
  return result;
};

export const deleteEntity: ICrudDeleteAction<IMedicine> = id => async dispatch => {
  const requestUrl = `${apiUrl}/${id}`;
  const result = await dispatch({
    type: ACTION_TYPES.DELETE_MEDICINE,
    payload: axios.delete(requestUrl)
  });
  dispatch(getEntities());
  return result;
};

export const reset = () => ({
  type: ACTION_TYPES.RESET
});
```

Comment: Yes, how will that help? I edited the question to make it more understandable. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 5):

The actions are triggered by [redux-promise-middleware](https://github.com/pburtchaell/redux-promise-middleware).

For an action `FOO` with an asynchronous payload, redux-promise-middleware will dispatch 3 actions:

- `FOO_PENDING`, immediately
- `FOO_FULFILLED`, once the promise is settled
- `FOO_REJECTED`, if the promise is rejected

REQUEST, SUCCESS and FAILURE are just 3 simple functions in JHispter to facilitate the use of redux-promise-middleware.

```
export const REQUEST = actionType => `${actionType}_PENDING`;
export const SUCCESS = actionType => `${actionType}_FULFILLED`;
export const FAILURE = actionType => `${actionType}_REJECTED`;
```

Comment: Thanks, that is all I was waiting for!